# Unit testing with Eclipse System Workbench (STM32)

Tags: stm32, eclipse

Although this is a pure software question, other Stack fora are not suitable since the application problem is only occuring for microprocessor usage.

I installed Eclipe System Workbench for developing STM32 applications which works ok.

However, now I want to do (offline) unit testing but g++ seems not to be installed. Only the Cross compiler/AC6 parts are installed.

When installing e.g. cygwin I get the same errors.

I develop on Windows. Does anybody has an idea how to do unit testing using Eclipse in combination with System Workbench for STM32, like what additional item(s) to install or what settings to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using something like CPPUTest. I have used this on CCS and I think the setup would be the same as it.

For your installation of g++/gcc, I suggest using MINGW if your Cygwin installation does not work. For further information and in depth detail check out the [CPPUTest Documentation](http://cpputest.github.io/)

Comment: Just wanted to throw in another unit testing framework: http://www.throwtheswitch.org/unity - I'm using it under both msys2 and Visual Studio